# Can OpenStreetMap be used as a WMS service in MapServer?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapserver, overlay

I want to produce a png image that uses OpenStreetMap data and has a vector overlaid on the base data. I am able to produce the vector overlay from within Mapserver, but I have difficulty understanding how to include an external data source like OpenStreetMap.

I would prefer to use an external service over loading the OpenStreetMap data directly as I wish to use it only as a basemap.

Is it possible to do this from within MapServer?

Answer (score 3):

This is documented [here](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_client.html). In short, you can add a WMS layer within your mapfile as follows:

```
    LAYER
      NAME "country_bounds"
      TYPE RASTER
      STATUS ON
      CONNECTION "http://demo.mapserver.org/cgi-bin/wms?"
      CONNECTIONTYPE WMS
      METADATA
        "wms_srs"             "EPSG:4326"
        "wms_name"            "country_bounds"
        "wms_server_version"  "1.1.1"
        "wms_format"          "image/gif"
      END
    END
```

There are OpenStreetMap WMS' available [here](http://www.osm-wms.de/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For the linked OSM WMS, do you know what the connection info would be? For example I can find `http://129.206.228.72/osm-proxy/service?` but nothing with `WMS` in the address.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use MapServer but the [MapServer with OSGeo4W Users Guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/59759871/19/Exercise-13-Consuming-Remote-WMS-Layers-in-MapServer-WMS-Client) seems likely describe the steps to enable MapServer to consume WMS in its Exercise 13: Consuming Remote WMS Layers in MapServer (WMS Client).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you think about meeting your requirements with a slightly different approach.

MapServer can cascade WMS services, but I am not aware of any public WMS services that serve up OSM data for free.  Most OSM data services that I am aware of use the tiled TMS specification.

If your version of MapServer is compiled with a version of GDAL that supports the TMS standard (via the WMS mini-driver) http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html, you can theoretically pull it off, but I don't believe that it is widely used.

The simplest solution is to keep the basemap and data layers separate on the server side and combine them in the client.  Configure your map client to use OSM data tiles from MapQuest Open, CloudMade, OSM, or someone else for the base layer.  Create a transparent layer for your own data and pull it into your client via WMS.

Make sure that you look at and honor the license/usage requirements for your source of OSM tiles.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am currently combining these on the browser side using `OpenLayers`, and an OSM base-map but I am interested in combining them on the server side also.

Comment: There is a free OSM-WMS at www.oms-wms.de (as dmci already pointed out).